# Failed writing a list in a csv file with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, raspberry-pi3

I have a python script, on my Raspberry pi 3, who managed the service_perfdata(.csv) of nagios.
I have to build this csv file for is reading in ruby with dashing (an IHM)
But after running the following code, my new csv file is empty.
there is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4.2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import csv
import sys
import os
import re

n=8
while True: 
    with open("/usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata.csv","r") as f:
        ligne=list(f)
        clean=str(ligne)
        int_list = [int(s) for s in re.findall ('\\d+',clean)] #extract int from the csv file of nagios
        n=8
        i=n
        while i<len(int_list): # add a line return at n step
            int_list.insert(i,"\n")
            i +=(n+1)

        j=3
        m=0
        x=1
        y=4
        while j<len(int_list): #concatenation of the date 
            int_list[m:j] = ['/'.join(map(str,int_list[m:j]))]
            m+=7
            j+=7

        while y<len(int_list):   #concatenation of the time 
            int_list[x:y] = ['-'.join(map(str,int_list[x:y]))]
            x+=5
            y+=5


    with open ("RAM.csv","w") as g :
        wtr = csv.writer(g,delimiter=',')
        w=0
        z=5
        while z < len(int_list): #rewrite of the list,line by line in my new csv file
            wtr.writerow(int_list[w:z])
            print (int_list[w:z])
            z+=5
            w+=5
        time.sleep(30)
```

and when I run it, i have this result in the Python Shell:

```
['12/20/2016', '0-49-36', 1032642560, 12, '\n']
['12/20/2016', '0-54-35', 1021329408, 12, '\n']
['12/20/2016', '0-59-34', 1023262720, 12, '\n']
['12/20/2016', '1-4-35', 1018642432, 12, '\n']
...
```

This is the result I want in my csv file, but I can't see any data in the file when I open it..maybe some body have an idea ?
actually, I am new in python, so i am available to any comment on my code.

Answer (score 0):

The data is actually written to the file. Probably you can't see it because you keep it open most of the time. I don't know why you are doing that, maybe you should put the program to sleep after the file has been closed.

Comment: I have find my mistake, I have to empty the buffer with that line `g.flush()` and I can find all my data in the file. Sorry for the disapointment but If I do this it's because the perdata in nagios return me a csv file inappropriate like this `12-20-2016 00:49:36;RAM Utilisation;'Physical Memory Used'=1032642560Bytes; 'Physical Memory Utilisation'=12%;-; `

Comment: the `g.flush()` was add at the end of the code just before the `time.spleep()` .

Comment: @thibaultbalay The format does not force you to keep the file open while sleeping. You are closing it after the sleep anyway, you might as well close it before. Closing the file will automatically flush it. I don't see the point of flushing the file, sleeping for 30 seconds with the file still open and then closing it.